# Android: How to retrieve MIDI events at the right time?

Tags: java, android, midi, javax.sound.midi

I am trying to retrieve all MIDI events **at the right time** from a MIDI file, within an **Android** app.

The following code works on a standard JVM (on my computer), using the `javax.sound.midi` API.

```
Sequencer sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer();

Sequence sequence = MidiSystem.getSequence(new File(FILENAME));
sequencer.setSequence(sequence);

sequencer.open();

sequencer.getTransmitter().setReceiver(new Receiver()
{
    @Override
    public void send(MidiMessage message, long timeStamp)
    {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(message.getMessage()));
    }

    @Override
    public void close()
    {
    }
});

sequencer.start();
```

Unfortunatelly, `javax.sound.*` package is not available on Android. A porting for Android is available on Github (https://github.com/kshoji/javax.sound.midi-for-Android) but my code sample above doesn't work (`sequencer.getTransmitter()` returns null).

Does anyone know how to do that? I didn't found any interesting library (http://www.midi.org/aboutmidi/android.php) for what I want to do.

Thank you.